# Static variables in ruby, like in C functions

Tags: ruby

Is there any such thing as static variables in Ruby that would behave like they do in C functions?

Here's a quick example of what I mean. It prints "6\n7\n" to the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test() {
        static int a = 5;
        a++;
        return a;
}

int main() {

        printf("%d\n", test());
        printf("%d\n", test());

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope your variable in a method and return lambda

```
def counter
  count = 0
  lambda{count = count+1}
end

test = counter
test[]
#=>1
test[]
#=>2
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as it seems closest to what I've asked. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidUnric closure? As opposed to clojure the language?

Answer (score 5):

What I understand about this C code is that the static variable is initialized with a value (`5` in this case), and its value is persisted across function calls.

In Ruby and languages with the same level of abstraction, this same thing is typically achieved either by using a variable that sits outside the scope of the function or by using an object to hold that variable.

```
def test()
  @a ||= 5 # If not set, set it. We need to use an instance variable to persist the variable across calls.
  @a += 1 # sum 1 and return it's value
end

def main()
  puts test
  puts test
  0
end
```

Ruby's quirk is that you can use instance variables even outside of a class definition.

Comment: In C and C++ static variables are created and initialized when the application first starts, not when the function containing them is run for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to nicooga's answer but more self-contained:

```
def some_method
  @var ||= 0
  @var += 1
  puts @var
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable:

```
$a = 5
def test
  $a += 1
end

p test #=> 6
p test #=> 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable in the singleton class (The static class itself)

```
class Single
  def self.counter
    if @count  
      @count+=1
    else
      @count = 5
    end
  end
end
```

In ruby, any class is an object which has only one instance.
Therefore, you can create an instance variable on the class, and it will work as a "static" method ;)

Output:

```
  ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]

=> :counter
   Single.counter
=> 5
   Single.counter
=> 6
   Single.counter
=> 7
```

To get this behaviour on the main scope, you can do:

```
module Countable
  def counter
    if @count  
      @count+=1
    else
      @count = 5
    end
  end
end

=> :counter
   self.class.prepend Countable # this "adds" the method to the main object
=> Object
   counter
=> 5
   counter
=> 6
   counter
=> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a standard way to do this is to use `Fiber`.

```
f = Fiber.new do
  a = 5
  loop{Fiber.yield a += 1}
end

puts f.resume # => 6
puts f.resume # => 7
...
```